# Fixing functionally of read-only ArcGIS Enterprise stack

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise

I have a full Enterprise deployment on one server machine (ArcGIS Server, Portal, and Datastore) that cannot currently create new hosted services, edit or add records on hosted services, or create new records in referenced services. I know for sure that the problems started because I added an instance of Survey123 on the same machine as the other components. And while all available resources indicated that there should be enough horsepower to work, it caused massive problems. The issues got better once I uninstalled Survey123. I have worked with ESRI to get some resolution, but am getting running around with troubleshooting.

I am thinking that I should cut my losses and build a new virtual instance. But am looking for some confirmation on that logic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone here can say based on the information provide you should "start over". However, sometimes it can be easier to use the nuclear option, especially if you don't have data/items inside that you'd lose or need to backup. That'll need to be a decision you make based on the amount of work to re-install vs. troubleshoot, taking into account what you lose.

If you're working with Support, I'm sure you've already come across or been given the [Read only mode](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/read-only-mode-in-arcgis-enterprise.htm) web help to read. Specifically, you've tried to re-set the flag to **False** and for some reason this hasn't fixed it. Per your note about installing Survey123 and this causing the problem -- I've never heard of that happening, nor could I speculate how/why.